# Variance and Standard Derivation of the averages

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

Suppose I have a sequence of sample points $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n,\ldots)$.

Assume that the average of the first $n$ samples $y_n := \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n x_k}{n}$ converges to a constant $\bar{x}$.

I want to study the convergence, so I consider $y_n - \bar{x}$.

Note that the average of the first $n$ samples of the sequence $(y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n,\ldots)$ also
converges to $\bar{x}$.

So I consider the standard derivation (If this is the right name) $\boldsymbol{\sigma}_n := \sqrt{\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}(y_k - \bar{x})^2}{n}}$ for the sequence $(y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n,\ldots)$. It is clear that $\boldsymbol{\sigma}_n \rightarrow 0$ if $n \rightarrow \infty$, since $y_n - \bar{x} \rightarrow0$.
So by studying the convergence of $\boldsymbol{\sigma}_n$, we know ***the average speed of the convergence*** of $y_n$ to $\bar{x}.$

But usually, the standard derivation is defined as $\sigma_n=\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}(x_k - y_k)^2}{n}}$, or we define it as $\sigma_n=\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}(x_k - \bar{x})^2}{n}}$. It measures the amount of variation or dispersion of a set of data values. This is an standard notion and usage in probability theory.

I would like to know if the usage of $\boldsymbol{\sigma}_n$ is also a standard tool in probability theory or statistics. And if so, what is the name for this quantity?

Comment: What is k? Can you specify

Comment: Sorry, a typo. See update

Comment: Using standard notation and terminology can't hurt when you want to be understood by people familiar with it.  The numbers $x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots$ are not "samples"; they are observations in a sample.  The terms in the sequence of "sample points" are not samples; rather the whole sequence is a sample.  It is commonplace to use $\bar x$ to mean the sample mean, i.e. the mean of the first $n$ observations, which depends on $n$; hence calling the limit as $n\to\infty$ by the name $\bar x$ is somewhat jarring. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is! But you have to be careful. In statistics $\sigma_n$ or just $\sigma$ is the standard deviation from a random variable. But most often we don't know the true standard deviation, so we have to estimate it. This is where your formula comes in. There is a theory of estimating parameters from a given distribution called the "maximum likelihood estimation". By this method we wan't to estimate a parameter, by maximizing the probabilty that a given distribution generate the given sample of data. This maximum likelihood estimator for the standard deviation $\sigma$ with a normal distributed random variable is:
$$\hat{\sigma} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n (x_k - \bar{x})^2}$$
If you compute the square $\hat{\sigma}^2$ you get an estimator for the variance.

Comment: by no means the estimator $\widehat{\sigma} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^n (x_k - \bar{x})^2}$ is unbiased. In fact it is very easy to show that it's biased. The fact that $\widehat{\sigma}^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^n (x_k - \bar{x})^2$ is unbiased doesn't mean that its square root is unbiased as well. Bessel's correction is correct only for the variance and not the standard deviation

Comment: @Nir Regev: Yes you're right. I never thought about that bevore. Thank's for clarification. I have definitely to edit the post. :)